# Powershell find the name of a user that created the account

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to filter for a  username based on the account that was created

For example sometext@gmail.com is the username

Currently I have the following `code`

```
Get-WinEvent  -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=624;data='sometext@gmail.com'}
```

The notes I'm working from say that account creation is Event IDs 624, 626

However I'm unable to return the above filter successfully

How is it possible to filter for a username associated with an account that was created ?

I have also tried the following which shows me account creation date but not the user who created it .

```
Get-EventLog  -FilterHashtable | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 4720 }:
```

Thanks

Comment: I rolled back your question to edit 2, since you removed a big chunk of your question. Even if something doesn't work it is nice to see what you have tried. Future readers might see this and say that "yes, this is exactly what I did" and know that they are reading a question related to their issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

624 is the ID for the "user account was created" event [prior to Windows Vista](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301677), 4720 is the ID for the same event in [Windows Vista and newer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn319091%28v=ws.11%29.aspx). According to [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17055.event-ids-when-a-new-user-account-is-created-on-active-directory.aspx) you should be able to extract the information who created the new account from the event message:

```
Subject:
          Security ID:             TESTLAB\Santosh
          Account Name:            Santosh
          Account Domain:          TESTLAB
          Logon ID:                0x8190601

New Account:
          Security ID:             TESTLAB\Random
          Account Name:            Random
          Account Domain:          TESTLAB

Attributes:
          SAM Account Name:        Random
          Display Name:            Random
          User Principal Name:     Random@AD.TESTLAB.NET
...
```

Something like this should work:

```
$upn = 'sometext@gmail.com'

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';Id=4720} |
  Where-Object { $_.Message -match "user principal name:\s+$upn" } |
  Select-Oject -Expand Message |
  Select-String '(?<=subject:\s+security id:\s+\S+\s+account name:\s+)\S+' |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  Select-Object -Expand Value
```

Comment: @NivekDefend Working _how_? While this answer may have provided the crucial pointer, it would still be helpful to see a complete solution, especially since you've removed your solution attempt from your question.

Comment: @mklement0 I think I can help with that ;)